# Is this possible to check what is the active programme on OS X using Java?

Tags: java, macos

Now the active programme is Safari:

[image]

And now, is Skype:

[image]

Is this possible to detect it? Thanks.

Comment: Everything is possible if you just believe.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Rococoa library, (https://code.google.com/p/rococoa/) and this answer: [How to programmatically determine the currently active App in OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143540/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-currently-active-app-in-os-x)

You should be able to accomplish this pretty easily.